# custom column name but get error List object is not callable

Tags: python-polars

I have csv and no header in it, I want provide header from list

import polars as pl

header = ["col1", "col2"]

df = pl.scan_csv(file_path, has_header = False, with_column_names = header,)

But get error list object is not callable

I try

with_column_names=header[:]

with_column_names=list(header)

Make def function which return list
with_column_names=def_fun(header)

All still error list not Callable

And

with_column_names=list[header]

With this no error list not callable but the header still auto generate with column_1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html), `with_column_names` is a  `Callable[[list[str]], list[str]]`.

You can try passing `with_column_names = lambda _: header`